# javascript - Wait for webpack bundle complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, webpack

I'm writing a Chrome extension modifying HTML DOM elements. I want to ask how could I wait for finished loading from websites bundled in webpack?

Answer (score 0):

**User window.onload**

When do window.onload fires?

By default, it is fired when the entire page loads, including its content (images, css, scripts, etc.)
In some browsers it now takes over the role of document.onload and fires when the DOM is ready as well.

Example:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // ..doSomethingElse.. 
};
```

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048

Comment: It does not solve. `webpack` content is still loaded after this event fires